# Remove buttons that are added at runtime

Tags: cocoa, button

I have a view that allows buttons to be created and added to at runtime.
This seems to be working correctly.

I have a series of background images that are cycled through the application when the user clicks a button on the main form.

This works fine, but the buttons that are added at runtime need to be removed whenever the user switches background images.

How do I remove the buttons that were added at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Send the button `[button removeFromSuperview];`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all of them:

```
for (UIButton* button in [[viewWithButtonsInIt.subviews copy] autorelease]) {
    if ([button.currentTitle hasPrefix:@"Prefix"]) { //or whatever condition you need
        [button removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

If the view contains other subviews, keep a list of the added buttons and enumerate over that instead.

Comment: The question doesn't specify OS X or iOS, so I will add this: This code will not work on OS X. You have to use a copy of the array returned by subviews if you want to use fast enumeration.

Comment: This is close, but I am having trouble getting to the information of the button to see if it falls within the parameters...   how can I view the information of the button as it cycle through them???

Comment: @pithhelmet: you'll probably want to type the button in that case, then check for a condition. I've updated the code